# can data be parsed from json file and displayed on a new window using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, json, session-storage

employee.html aims at parsing a json file and storing values in sessionStorage.Is it the correct approach to display values from a json file on a new html page? Is it possible to do so using only html and javascript?

```
"employee.html"

<html>
<head>
  <title>Employee Profile</title>
       <script language="javascript">
          function fun(){
                 var file =document.getElementById("profile").files.item(0);
                 var reader = new FileReader(); 
                 reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");  
                 reader.onload = loadedFile;    
                 }
          function loadedFile(event){ 
                var fileString = event.target.result;
                var obj=JSON.parse(fileString);
                var str= JSON.stringify(obj);
                sessionStorage.setItem("name",obj.empInfo.name);
                sessionStorage.setItem("code",obj.empInfo.code);
            }  
         </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="display.html">
    <h4>Upload</h4>
    <input type="file" name="profile" id="profile"/> 
    <br><BR>
    <input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="submit" />
 </form>
 <hr>
 </body>
</html>
```

given below is display.html which aims to take value from sessionStorage and display it on the page

```
"display.html"
<html>
 <head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.write("hello");
var name=sessionStorage.getItem("name");
document.write(name);
}
 </script>
 </head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not able to get an output to this code.

Comment: Yes. If it's not working for you, try a simplified version.